# How to read text file in UTF8 format using IO?

Tags: powershell, io

How to read text files using some encoding in powershell?

I am doing the following:

```
$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("path.txt")
$text
```

But I needed to put the UTF8 encode, how can I do that?

Comment: You target [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-readalllines(system-string-system-text-encoding))?

Comment: I managed to put `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

Comment: As aside, `(gi path.txt).OpenText().ReadToEnd()` is probably better than doing that, it should automatically detect the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("path.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

Comment: Nice - that's definitely the right overload to use when a specific encoding must be used, but it's worth noting that UTF-8 is .NET's _default_ encoding (when _writing_, it is _BOM-less_ UTF-8).